# SQL Server generic Collation

Tags: sql-server, collation

I need to create a database in SQL Server, which will be able to support English, Hebrew and Arabic.

How can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use nvarchar instead of varchar fields. The collation is mainly used for sorting

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into how to use collations.(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144260.aspx)

SQL Server 2008 allows you to set the collation at the column level.  This means, for example, you could have a product table with description columns in each language, English, Hebrew, and Arabic.